# PHP mail special characters in subject field

Tags: php, email, character-encoding, special-characters

I would like to insert special characters in the subject of HTML e-mails sent with the PHP mail() function.

I want my subject to look like this:

**★ Your new account**

I have tried with an HTML entity like `&starf;` (★) or by pasting the symbol directly in my code but that doesn't work either, except on a few e-mail clients.

```
$to = 'me@example.com';
$subject = '★ Your new account or &starf; Your new account';
$message = 'HTML message...';

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Me <me@example.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Any advice on how to get this to work properly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try for subject:

```
$sub = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
```

And then:

```
mail($to, $sub, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Tested and it works with the symbol, not with the HTML entity. Thank you.

Comment: Can confirm this works for Swedish characters (Å, Ä, Ö)

Comment: The only one that works. Very nice. I used in from field in the headers array

Comment: Works also for german characters: Ä, ä, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

While the accepted answer works fine, it makes it impossible to read the subject when looking at the raw headers.  Here's an alternative that keeps the line readable and also shorter if it consists of mostly ascii characters.

```
$subject = '=?UTF-8?q?' . quoted_printable_encode($subject) . '?=';
```

Here's the encoded subject line of the accepted answer:

```
=?UTF-8?B?4piFIFlvdXIgbmV3IGFjY291bnQ=?=
```

Here's the encoded subject line of my answer:

```
=?UTF-8?q?=E2=98=85 Your new account?=
```

**Edit:**

It turns out `quoted_printable_encode()` splits long strings into multiple lines of max 75 characters, as required per RFC 2045.  This resulted is a string that cannot be used with `mail()`'s `$subject` parameter.  Here's an updated version to fix this.  It will also avoid encoding pure-ascii subjects.

```
/**
 * Make sure the subject is ASCII-clean
 *
 * @param string $subject Subject to encode
 *
 * @return string Encoded subject
 */
function getEncodedSubject(string $subject): string {
    if (!preg_match('/[^\x20-\x7e]/', $subject)) {
        // ascii-only subject, return as-is
        return $subject;
    }
    // Subject is non-ascii, needs encoding
    $encoded = quoted_printable_encode($subject);
    $prefix = '=?UTF-8?q?';
    $suffix = '?=';
    return $prefix . str_replace("=\r\n", $suffix . "\r\n  " . $prefix, $encoded) . $suffix;
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
$subj = "Lorem ipsuöm dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent mattis molestie purus, non semper lectus dictum eget.";
```

After `quoted_printable_encode`

```
Lorem ipsu=C3=B6m dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent mat=
tis molestie purus, non semper lectus dictum eget.
```

After `str_replace`

```
=?UTF-8?q?Lorem ipsu=C3=B6m dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent mat?=
  =?UTF-8?q?tis molestie purus, non semper lectus dictum eget.?=
```

Comment: Note that there are more differences between `quoted_printable_encode()`, which implements quoted printable for the e-mail body from RFC2045 and the needed quoted printable encoding for headers from RFC2047. In particular, for headers, spaces must be replaced by `_` and `_` must be encoded by `=5F`. Also, RFC2047 *does* limit line length, but forbids one run of encoded text to span over multiple lines. There might be more differences, but it is probably better to just implement your own quoted-printable rather than using the `quoted_printable_encode` function.

Comment: One correction, spaces must be encoded as `_` or `=20`, the latter seems more common (but the former was allowed for readability IIUC).

Answer (score 1):

```
 $headers="";    
 $message = utf8_encode($message);
 $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
 $subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode(utf8_encode($subject)).'?=';
 $to_name = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode(utf8_encode($to_name)).'?=';
 $from_name = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode(utf8_encode($from_name)).'?=';

 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n"; 
 //$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . "\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: $from_name <$from_email>" . "\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "To: $to_name <$to_email>" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Subject: $subject" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();  

 mail("", $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you change HEADERS Charset to **charset=iso-8859-1**, then you can simply paste the "emoji' in the subject.

This works for me - emails have sad face in subject. Also worked for "From":

```
$subject = "Email subject";
$headers = "From: Me <me@example.com> \r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$sub =   " ". $subject;
mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers);
```

**NOTE:** I edited this in cPanel File Editor. I don't know if this will work if edited in local code editor, and uploaded via FTP