# Use Japanese characters in subject and attach file with mailx in RedHat Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mailx

I am trying to use the `mailx` command for sending email with attachment (zipped) and am facing two issues, below is the command I use:

```
(echo "$BODY"; UUENCODE $ZIP_FILE $ZIP_FILE) \
 | mailx -s $SUBJECT_1 -r " " $SENDER $RECIPIENT
```

My email subject contains space and Japanese characters.

The variable `$SUBJECT_1`  has the following statement

```
Subject: [Budget] Subtype Error and some JAPANESE CHARECTERS
```

I get bet following error:

```
contains invalid character '\203'
```

Moreover for testing purpose I changed the statement of `SUBJECT_1` to `Test Message`

```
SUBJECT_1="Test Message"
```

It worked, but I receive only `Test` instead of `Test Message` and in the mail I could see two more email ids in the `To` like `Message@domain.com` and `-r@domain.com`

I have not implemented the mail body yet, once subject issue fixed will implement the same in body because Body will also have Japanese characters.

Please help me with this error, how to resolve and what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a list of things you need help with here, more than I want to to handle exhaustively on a sunny Saturday afternoon. But some hints.

**Quote your variables.**

`"$SUBJECT_1"` is a single string, whereas `$SUBJECT_1` is a list of space-separated words. The second word is your email recipient, and subsequent options are also recipients.

**Subject.**

The basic idea is that you need to include encoding data in the subject, because email headers are only supposed to include 7-bit ASCII.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20806227/1072112) is a hint at how you put special characters in your Subject line.

[Here](https://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/) is another hint.

[Here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1522.txt) is the RFC that describes in lurid detail what you need to do. Asking your favourite search engine for information about "utf8 email subject" and "rfc1522" is probably a good idea.

**Email client.**

Finally, rather than learning how to use MIME, consider using [`mutt`](http://mutt.org/) instead of `mailx` to send your mail. Mutt has a `-a` option to add attachments, making it WAY easier than constructing your own headers and body, which I'm not even sure you'd be able to do with mailx in the first place.

Comment: Thanks.. Ghoti.. the first part of the issue is resolved after adding the double quotes, now checking the Japanese Charecter issue, Regarding you Mutt suggestion should we need to instance anything? is this library/feature inbuilt to Redhat Linux/bash ?
BTW let me try the options and will let you know..

Comment: Sorry for asking some elementary questions. 
I tried the option mentioned in the link you provided like below
`$SUBJECT_1 = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($SUBJECT).'?=';`
I put the above code in the shell script before calling the mailx but I get a syntax error `'('` unexpected.

Comment: No worries, we all started somewhere. Regarding `base64_encode()`, note that this is a **PHP** function. It was a hint, not an instruction. You'd need to find something in bash that does what that PHP function does (try `man base64` from a shell), or copy the results of that function in to your bash script. As for mutt, it's an add-on package that is likely available in Redhat using whatever package manager you use to install other third-party software. After you install, run `man bash` to see usage instructions.